# Why a WrongMethodTypeException from MethodHandle? Is my object type incorrect?

Tags: java, reflection, methodhandle

I have encountered a problem while I am trying to switch my event system from reflection to MethodHandle.

I am using an event bus (version 3.0.0) by KyoriPowered on Github (https://github.com/KyoriPowered/event).

My code is following:

```java
public class EventExecutorFactory implements EventExecutor.Factory<Event, Listener> {
    @Override
    public @NonNull EventExecutor<Event, Listener> create(@NonNull Object object, @NonNull Method method) throws Exception { // object is Listener
        method.setAccessible(true);
        Class<? extends Event> actualEventType = method.getParameterTypes()[0].asSubclass(Event.class);
        MethodHandle handle = MethodHandles.lookup().unreflect(method);
        return new EventExecutor<Event,Listener>() {

            @Override
            public void invoke(@NonNull Listener listener, @NonNull Event event) throws Throwable {
                if (!actualEventType.isInstance(event)) return; // many different event types defined in my system, so I should check it first.
                handle.invoke(actualEventType.cast(event)); // WrongMethodTypeException thrown here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expected this to work fine, but the result is:

> java.lang.invoke.WrongMethodTypeException: cannot convert MethodHandle(,UserOnlineEvent)void to (Event)void

UserOnlineEvent is the event type that used in test.

The problem is that I cannot get the real type of the event.

---

Edit: This problem has been solved. I should use two arguments.
just add the listener as the first argument to handle.invoke, and it works.

Comment: Is that the whole exception message? It looks like some other type should go before the comma in `MethodHandle(,UserOnlineEvent)`, also the return type is missing.

Comment: Are you trying to invoke a static method? If not, then the MethodHandle will have 2 arguments.

Comment: @JornVernee Oh, I'm sorry, the return type is void and I've edited it. I don't know the meaning of the comma, the whole exception message is right here.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Of course not, I will try it later.

Comment: Note that `actualEventType.cast(…)` is obsolete here. You already did the `actualEventType.isInstance(…)` check and `handle.invoke(…)` will perform a type cast anyway.

Comment: @Holger I know, current code in my system has already edited.

Answer (score 0):

According to your message , I find the code in JDK. at `MethodHandle#asTypeUncached`

```java
/*non-public*/ 
MethodHandle asTypeUncached(MethodType newType) {
        if (!type.isConvertibleTo(newType))
            throw new WrongMethodTypeException("cannot convert "+this+" to "+newType);
        return asTypeCache = MethodHandleImpl.makePairwiseConvert(this, newType, true);
    }
```

it's clear, I guess parameter type is wrong. if debug , you will find it.

Comment: I'm sure the UserOnlineEvent is a subclass of Event. But how can I cast it? The real type is unknown and unreachable in the code.

Comment: have you debug it? if have , can you provide a Github link. I will try it.

Comment: I have tried the advice from Johannes Kuhn. And it works. This problem has solved. Thanks.